# Runner.app size is about 400mb. How to reduce it?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

I'm developing flutter app using `flutter_tts` library which is written on `swift`, so I have to use `swift` as build language for ios otherwise it won't work. Release build size for `android` is about 20-30mb, but for ios is almost **400 mb**. This is not because of assets. I read about this problem and a lot of people said that this is because swift, so I created a hello world app and compared release build sizes: `objc: ~20mb` and `swift: ~65mb`. Unfortunately, I have no choice. Now `Flutter` build for ios is 10-15 times bigger than for android. **400 mb** – it seems like a joke, obviously it's inappropriate. Even if I convert `Runner.app` to `ipa` file, the size will be about **200mb**. This is too large size to download app from `AppStore`.

Am I doing something wrong? Could someone help me? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem (Runner.app ~ 360 mb).

First check your Flutter SDK version:

```
flutter --version
```

You may not be using the latest version, or you’re in an unstable channel. Switch to the stable channel and update the Flutter SDK:

```
flutter channel stable
flutter upgrade --force
```

Build a project:

```
flutter clean
flutter build ios --release
```

Version:

```
Flutter 1.9.1+hotfix.6 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 68587a0916 (6 weeks ago) • 2019-09-13 19:46:58 -0700
Engine • revision b863200c37
Tools • Dart 2.5.0
```

Build size decreased to 54.5 MB and .ipa file to 21.8 MB.